# Server can not receive httpPOST parameters when I use Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, http, alamofire

I Send a HTTP request by  Alamofire,but the server can not receive post parameter.

```
    let netParams = NetParams()
    let ramdomStr = netParams.get16Strings()
    let timeStamp = netParams.genTimeStamp()
    let signDic:Dictionary<String,String> = ["version":"ios","timestamp":timeStamp!,"nonce":ramdomStr!,"event":"sngfcinformation"]

    let sign = netParams.genSign(signDic)
    //var obj = AseEncry()
    let enStr = AseEncry .aseEn(withPlant: sign, andSecret: secretStr)
    let params:Dictionary<String,String> = ["version":"ios","timestamp":timeStamp!,"nonce":ramdomStr!,"event":"sngfcinformation","sign":enStr!]
    var returnDic:Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = ["a":"b" as AnyObject]

    Alamofire.request(sngfcURL+"news/index.action", method: .post, parameters:params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint("jsonhead")
            debugPrint(response.result.value ?? AnyClass.self)
            debugPrint("jsonend")

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                returnDic = JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
               // block(dic:returnDic)

            }
    }
        .responseString { (response) in
            debugPrint("head")

            debugPrint(response.result.value!)
            debugPrint("end")

    }
```

Server can response me ,but can not receive any paramer.
Then I use AFNetWoring,it is work well and server get correct paramers.

```
 +(void)XYNetWorkWithParams:(NSDictionary*)dics withUrl:(NSString*)url withSuccessBlock:(backBlock)successBlock withfailBlock:(backBlock)failBlock{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *mgr=[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

   NSString *netaddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://61.152.245.216/sngfc.mobile/news/index.action?"];
   [mgr POST:netaddress parameters:dics success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      NSDictionary *dic = responseObject;
      successBlock(dic);     
   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
      failBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"fail",@"msg", nil]);        
   }];
}
```

what's wrong when I use Alamofire?

Comment: seems issue in request parameter encoding, change  `JSONEncoding.default` to `URLEncoding.httpBody`.